# load() and source() throw error in opening a RData file

Tags: r, rdata

I am trying to open an RData file containing a zoo object with a column for timestamp and a couple of columns containing some data. It has about 300,000 rows in it.

Upon using the command `load(dest)` command I get the following error

```
Error: bad restore file magic number (file may be corrupted) -- no data loaded
In addition: Warning message:
file ‘zoo.RData’ has magic number 'RDX3'
  Use of save versions prior to 2 is deprecated
```

I searched online for a solution and I got a suggestion to use `source()` instead of `load()`. Upon using `source(dest)` I got the following error:

```
Error in source("zoo.RData") : 
  invalid multibyte character in parser at line 4
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In grepl("\n", lines, fixed = TRUE) :
  input string 4 is invalid in this locale
2: In grepl("\n", lines, fixed = TRUE) :
  input string 5 is invalid in this locale
3: In grepl("\n", lines, fixed = TRUE) :
  input string 7 is invalid in this locale
4: In grepl("\n", lines, fixed = TRUE) :
  input string 8 is invalid in this locale
5: In grepl("\n", lines, fixed = TRUE) :
  input string 9 is invalid in this locale
```

[This](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CdgMbeaRaCYXH0LIFDLKrY1xgRoqRWRS/view?usp=sharing) is a google drive link to the dataset in case anyone would like to have a look:

I am on a MacOS 13.4.0 machine using R version 3.3.2

Thanks

Comment: hey Vizag, I could load your file... it is zoo' num [1:234000]

Comment: Yes. It opened on other systems but not on mine. Any clue from the errors I posted?

Comment: I am on a mac too. R version? I hope not...

Comment: btw, that R version is ancient...

Comment: Maybe updating it might help. I'll check. What version are you on?

Comment: let me check whether others encounter this. i am on 3.6.1

Comment: `source` is used to open plain text files of R commands and execute them. You have a binary file with an `.RData` extension.

Comment: Hey. Turns out updation of Base R was needed. I updated it to 3.6.1 and it worked. Thanks :)